# React Native component with Redux is re-rendering on every addition of new record to the Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux

I have a React Native component that uses Redux to manage the state. The component has a useSelector hook that selects records from the Redux store. Every time a new record is added to the store, the whole component re-renders(including all components in the FlashList). This causes the RecordCard component to re-render unnecessarily(every time a record is added, all existing records are re-rendered), resulting in poor performance.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

**Component**

```
const RecordsScreen = () => {
    const records: { [key: string]: SingleRecord[] } = useSelector(selectFilteredRecords, shallowEqual);

    const keys = Object.keys(records);
    const keyExtractor = useCallback((item: any, index: number) => index, []);

    class RenderItem extends React.PureComponent {
        render() {
            const { dateString } = this.props;
            const dateRecords = records[dateString];
            return (
                <Collapsible>
                    <FlashList
                        data={dateRecords}
                        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => (<RecordCard record={item} />)}
                        removeClippedSubviews={true}
                        estimatedItemSize={dateRecords.length === 0 ? 1 : dateRecords.length}
                    />
                </Collapsible>
            );
        }
    }

    function areEqual(prevProps: any, nextProps: any) {        
        return JSON.stringify(prevProps) === JSON.stringify(nextProps);
    }
    const Memoized = memo(RenderItem, areEqual);

    return (
        <View>
            <FlashList
                data={keys}
                keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                renderItem={({ dateString }) => (<Memoized dateString={dateString} />)}
                removeClippedSubviews={true}
                estimatedItemSize={keys.length === 0 ? 1 : keys.length}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

export default RecordsScreen;
```

**Redux code**

```
interface RecordsState {
    records: { [key: string]: SingleRecord[] }; // where the key is a date in string format
    recordsFilter: Filter;

}

const initialState: RecordsState = {
    records: {},
    recordsFilter: new Filter()
};

...

// using reselect
export const selectFilteredRecords = createSelector(
    selectRecords,
    selectRecordsFilter,
    (records, filter) => {
        return filterRecords(records, filter);
    }
);

const filterRecords = (records: any, filter: any) => {
    const filteredRecords: { [key: string]: SingleRecord[] } = {};

    if (records !== null && records !== undefined) {
        Object.entries(records).forEach(([dateKey, records]: any) => {
            const filteredRecords = records.filter((record: any) => {
                if (filter.fromDate && record.date! < new Date(filter.fromDate)) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (filter.toDate && record.date! > new Date(filter.toDate)) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (filter.account && record.account !== filter.account) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (filter.category && record.category !== filter.category) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (filter.subCategory && record.subCategory !== filter.subCategory) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (filter.currency && filter.currency !== record.currency) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
            if (filteredRecords.length > 0) {
                filteredRecords[dateKey] = filteredRecords;
            }
        });
    }
    return filteredRecords;
}
```

I am using the shallowEqual equality function in the useSelector hook to prevent unnecessary re-renders, but it did not help.

I have tried using the React.memo higher-order component to memoize the RecordCard and the Collapsible components, but it did not solve the problem.

I have also tried using the useCallback hook to memoize the keyExtractor function, but it did not solve the problem.

What can I do to prevent the unnecessary re-renders caused by the useSelector hook?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should never declare a component like your `RenderItem` component here inside of another component - it will not only be rerendered, it will be treated as a completely different component by React. The DOM of that component will be removed, and a new DOM will be created. All internal state of that component and it's children will be lost every time. Define this component outside and pass in props.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector result doesn't seem to ever be shallowly equal - it will be an object of all-new arrays every time.

You can't solve this on the `useSelector` call site level, but you can memoize your selector instead. Give [deriving data with selectors](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors) a read.